# Editing files with with lists in C#?

Tags: c#, list, file

I'm trying to teach myself how to edit files in C# and have encountered a problem. I am trying to allow the user to open a file that contains a sentence that says:

```
"How are you today, <name>?"
```

I have a class that will read the file and add the sentence to a List. Here is the code that I wrote for that:

```
class FileReader
    {
        public string reader(string sentence)
        {
             string f = sentence;

            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
            {

                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    lines.Add(line);
                }
                return lines.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

Once this is returned as a string, I have another class that will read the list, and then will ask the user for a name. It will then replace `<name>` with the name the user input. Here is the code I've tried writing to handle this:

```
class Asker
        {
            public string asker(string sentence)
            {
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                string text = File.ReadAllText(sentence);
                text = text.Replace("<name>", name);
                lines.Add(text);
                File.WriteAllText(sentence, text);
                return lines.ToString();
            }

        }
```

By the end of this class, the Asker class should return a list containing the new sentence where `name` now replaces `<name>` in the original sentence. In main, I get an error code every time I try to run it. Here is main:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.Write("Enter the name of the story file: ");
                string filename = Console.ReadLine();
                FileReader read = new FileReader();
                string uneditedSentence = read.reader(filename);
                Asker ask = new Asker();
                string newSentence = ask.asker(uneditedSentence);
                Console.WriteLine(newSentence);
            }
```

When I run this program I get a message that it stopped working and just crashes.

Comment: Does it happens after inputting the file name ??

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava It happens after I enter `name`. Opening the file doesn't give me an error.

Comment: the uneditedScentence you passed to ask.asker is not a filename...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Edits are required in your code:

1) When you are returning lines.toString()>> it would return System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] and not the text in the file. So you should lines and not lines.String().
so the return type of your function would be List. 
Or if you want to return the string  then code would be:

```
class FileReader
{
    public string reader(string sentence)
    {
        string f = sentence;

        string lines = "";

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {

            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                lines +=line+ Environment.NewLine;
            }

            return lines;
        }

    }
}
```

2) In your asker class: asker function argument is the content of file and not the filename:

```
     string text = File.ReadAllText(sentence)
```

so the above code will not work.

A better way: you dont need file reader class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the name of the story file: ");
        string filename = Console.ReadLine();


        Asker ask = new Asker();
        string newSentence = ask.asker(filename);
        Console.WriteLine(newSentence);
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Asker
{
    public string asker(string sentence)
    {

        Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string text = File.ReadAllText(sentence);
        text = text.Replace("<name>", name);

        File.WriteAllText(sentence, text);
        return text;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to get rid of the unnecessary class as you and Yeldar recommended. I was trying to add classes to make this program more OOP but I can see why having FileReader class wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `reader` method accepts filename as the only argument and returns the **contents** of the file.

It means that in this line of code `uneditedSentence` is the contents of file `filename`:

```
string uneditedSentence = read.reader(filename);
```

Then, you pass this `uneditedSentence` to your `asker`:

```
string newSentence = ask.asker(uneditedSentence);
```

At the same time, your `asker` method has the following lines:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(sentence);
File.WriteAllText(sentence, text);
```

which expects **filepath** while you provide **contents** of it.

It provides a error, because you provide an incorrect file path. The reason of this is very simple - naming. You name your variables inproperly and get confused.

Refer to MSDN documentation on [ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) and [WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, it will not show proper results, because you apply `ToString()` to the `List<string>` expecting that it will be converted to the single string. However, it will simply result in something like `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`.

Here is how you should have done this:

```
class FileReader // Actually, it is a useless class, get rid of it
{
    public string Read(string filename)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(filename);
    }
}
```